# C# Having a dumb Moment when calling method with array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have this working almost as intended. The program it self is functional but the output is kinda screwy. It requires multiple hits of of the return key in order to display the contents of the array which is in a for loop and being called by the output() method.

=( seems like a simple enough thing but I am not seeing my problem.

My second issue is the fact that I call output(arr) ONCE but the output prints multiple instances of the array based on the size of the array....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value;

        Console.Write("How big of an Array? ");
        int arraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr = new int[arraySize];


        for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("First Value: ");
            value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }

        output(arr);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void output(Array arr)
    {

        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < arr.Length; v++)
            {
                string number = "Value: ";
                string arrayPoint = "Array Section: ";

                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}\t{2}{3}", arrayPoint, v, number, i);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this `Convert.ToInt32(value)` when `value` is already an `int` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things in your code,

Your output method is receiving parameter of type `Array`, instead it should be receiving `int[]`, and you should loop it once, not twice.

```
static void output(int[] arr)
        {
                for (int v = 0; v < arr.Length; v++)
                {
                    string number = "Value: ";
                    string arrayPoint = "Array Section: ";

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}\t{2}{3}", arrayPoint, v, number, arr[v]);
                }
        }
```

2nd, in your Main method you are using the prompt Enter First Value, which is somewhat confusing when the user is suppose to enter the value for the 2nd or later elements, you may change it to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize - 1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("Value for Element {0}: ",i));
        value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // or you can do
        arr[i] = value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need one loop in the *output* method.  Try like this ...

```
static void output(Array arr)
{
    for (int v = 0; v < arr.Length; v++)
    {
        string number = "Value: ";
        string arrayPoint = "Array Section: ";

        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}\t{2}{3}", arrayPoint, v, number, arr.GetValue(v));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is still giving me multiple outputs of the same info based on array size and is not displaying the entire array with one hit of the return key.

Comment: arr[v] will cause an error , cannot apply indexing with an expression of type Array

Comment: @Habib.OSU thanks, I didn't realize.  Changed it to *arr.GetValue*